# Property of Orthogonal matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, orthogonal-matrices

As I was going through a few examples of $3×3$ orthogonal matrices I observed a property in them that
$$
\lvert\det A\rvert=\lvert\det B\rvert
$$
where $A$ is upper left corner $2×2$ matrix and $B$ is lower right corner $1×1$ matrix.
If this is true is there some way of proving it?

Comment: Use Cramer's rule for the inverse of $A$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng can you please elaborate more what exactly is the approach I am still unable to prove

Comment: Here's the inverse of $A$ via Cramer's rule, but I don' t yet know how this helps:$$
\begin{align}
c_{11} = \frac{\det\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & a_{12} \\ 0 & a_{22} \end{array} \right]}{\det A} \qquad\qquad
c_{12} = \frac{\det\left[ \begin{array}{cc} a_{11} & 1 \\ a_{21} & 0 \end{array} \right]}{\det A} \\ {} \\
c_{21} = \frac{\det\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & a_{12} \\ 1 & a_{22} \end{array} \right]}{\det A} \qquad\qquad
c_{22} = \frac{\det\left[ \begin{array}{cc} a_{11} & 0 \\ a_{21} & 1 \end{array} \right]}{\det A}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This is true, and works more generally for any $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122639/sub-determinants-of-an-orthogonal-matrix (I've voted to close as a duplicate.  In the interest of full disclosure, I have the accepted answer on the other question.)